# Oracle PL/SQL trigger that updates a different table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm doing this exercise for university and I've been stuck for a week. I need to create a trigger so that when the status column on table "tbvale" is changed a few updates happen on column "tbfuncionario" accordingly.
I realize my code probably looks cumbersome and even inappropriate perhaps but it's an uni exercise designed to teach specific things.
That's what I came up with so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER status_chg
AFTER UPDATE OF status ON tbvale
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    nvd tbfuncionario.numvalesdescontados%type;
    nva tbfuncionario.numvalesaberto%type;
    vtva tbfuncionario.valortotalvalesaberto%type;
    nve tbfuncionario.numvalesemitidos%type;
    vv tbvale.valorvale%type;
    cod tbvale.fkcodmat%type;
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN
    IF (:NEW.status <> :OLD.status) THEN
        SELECT valorvale INTO vv FROM tbvale;
        SELECT fkcodmat INTO cod FROM tbvale;
        IF (:NEW.status = 2) THEN
            nvd := 1;
            nva := -1;
            nve := 0;
            vv := vv - 1;
        ELSE
            nvd := 0;
            nve := 1;
            nva := 1;
            vv := vv + 1;
        END IF;
        UPDATE tbfuncionario
        SET numvalesdescontados = numvalesdescontados + nvd,
            numvalesaberto = numvalesaberto + nva,
            numvalesemitidos = numvalesemitidos + nve,
            valortotalvalesaberto = valortotalvalesaberto + vv
        WHERE pkcodmat = cod;
    END IF;
END;
```

pkcodmat is the PK of tbfuncionario and fkcodmat is the FK of tbvale referencing pkcodmat.

Currently when I run

```
UPDATE tbvale SET STATUS = 2 WHERE PKCODVALE = 3;
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested 
number of rows ORA-06512: at "ULBRA.STATUS_CHG", line 11 
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ULBRA.STATUS_CHG' 

Error Code: 1422

Query = UPDATE tbvale SET STATUS = 2 WHERE PKCODVALE = 3
```

I don't understand why it would "return more than requested number of rows" as there is only one row where pkcodmat is equal to fkcodmat.

I appreciate any insights as to why that is happening and how I could fix it.

Comment: add a where clause to the select statements in the body of the trigger.

Comment: These queries must return single row: `SELECT valorvale INTO vv FROM tbvale;`
        `SELECT fkcodmat INTO cod FROM tbvale;`

Comment: "'Ive been stuck for a week"  If you had run `SELECT valorvale FROM tbvale;` on its own you could have saved yourself six days, twenty-three hours and fifty-nine days of stuckedness. 
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need these queries which are causing the exception:

```
SELECT valorvale INTO vv FROM tbvale;
SELECT fkcodmat INTO cod FROM tbvale;
```

Assuming you want the values from the `tbvale` row being updated, use the `:old` or `:new` record as appropriate e.g.

```
vv := :new.valorvalue;
cod := :new.fkcodmat;
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work. I'll make a few test to be sure but so far so good!

Answer (score 2):

The trigger look quite good. Here are some points:

1. `IF (:NEW.status <> :OLD.status)` doesn't detect changes form and to NULL, in case the column is nullable. Rather than `IF` inside the body, I'd use the triggers `WHEN` clause instead.
2. You are using column types for the variables. These however are only supposed to hold integers. No need hence for the columns types.
3. `SELECT valorvale INTO vv FROM tbvale`, This doesn't work. You want the value of one row, so you'd need a `WHERE` clause. But as you are supposedly interested in the current records value, you can simply use `:new.valorvale`.
4. Same for `SELECT fkcodmat INTO cod FROM tbvale`.
5. An autonomous trigger needs `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` at the end.

Here is the trigger corrected:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER status_chg
AFTER UPDATE OF status ON tbvale
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (DECODE(NEW.STATUS, OLD.STATUS, 0, 1) = 1)
DECLARE
  v_vd integer;
  v_va integer;
  v_ve integer;
  v_vv tbvale.valorvale%type;
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  IF (:NEW.status = 2) THEN
    v_vd := 1;
    v_va := -1;
    v_ve := 0;
    v_vv := :NEW.valorvale - 1;
  ELSE
    v_vd := 0;
    v_va := 1;
    v_ve := 1;
    v_vv := :NEW.valorvale + 1;
  END IF;

  UPDATE tbfuncionario
  SET numvalesdescontados = numvalesdescontados + v_vd,
      numvalesaberto = numvalesaberto + v_va,
      numvalesemitidos = numvalesemitidos + v_ve,
      valortotalvalesaberto = valortotalvalesaberto + v_vv 
  WHERE pkcodmat = :NEW.fkcodmat;

  COMMIT;
END;
```

And here is the same trigger without variables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER status_chg
AFTER UPDATE OF status ON tbvale
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (DECODE(NEW.STATUS, OLD.STATUS, 0, 1) = 1)
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  UPDATE tbfuncionario
  SET numvalesdescontados = numvalesdescontados + CASE WHEN :NEW.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    , numvalesaberto = numvalesaberto + CASE WHEN :NEW.status = 2 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END
    , numvalesemitidos = numvalesemitidos + CASE WHEN :NEW.status = 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    , valortotalvalesaberto = valortotalvalesaberto + :NEW.valorvale + CASE WHEN :NEW.status = 2 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END
  WHERE pkcodmat = :NEW.fkcodmat;

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I do understand the changes you made. There is one mistake though that I made when copying my code. The value of :NEW.valorvale should be subtracted or added to valortotalvalesaberto rather that adding or subtracting 1 (not sure I made myself clear). That's easy to correct with a (*) instead of a (+), is that right? (valortotalvalesaberto = valortotalvalesaberto + :NEW.valorvale * CASE WHEN :NEW.status = 2 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END). Other than that when I tried your code I got "ERROR: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis".

Comment: Yes, your solution with a factor works fine. An alternative is `= valortotalvalesaberto + CASE WHEN :NEW.status = 2 THEN - :NEW.valorvale ELSE :NEW.valorvale END`. Sorry about the missing parentheses; the `WHEN` clause needs them. I've updated my answer.